# MongoDB full text search does not work on specific words (which are not stop words)

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a VPS with MongoDB 4.4.x and PHP7.x and use the MongoDB PHP library to connect with MongoDB.

My documents (approx. 10 million) look like:

collection: tenants, fulltext index on answers.answer

```
"survey_id": {
    "$numberLong": "424221"
},
"account_id": 20014,
"feedback_id": 738857,
"date_reg": "2021-04-22",
"time_reg": "21:15",
"source": 2,
"trigg": 1,
"read_status": 0,
.... etc...,
"answers": {
    "0": {
        "answer": "Feedback answer 1 lorem ipsum gmail doramet",
        "type": 1,
        "qid": 4241,
        "datatype": 24,
        "additional": "",
        "q": "What do you think about..."
    },
    "1": {
        "answer": "Feedback answer steve lorem ipsum",
        "type": 2,
        "qid": 21,
        "datatype": 2,
        "additional": "",
        "q": "What was your experience with..."
    },
   ... etc...
```

Then I search like this:

```
$manager = new 
MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017");
$filter = ['$text' => ['$search' => "steve"]];
$options = ['limit' => 10];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter,$options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.tenants', $query);

foreach($cursor as $row){
  
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($row);
  echo '</pre><br><br>';
  
  
  $i++;

  }
```

This doesn't return the answer with "steve" in it.
However, if I search for "gmail" that does work. So why not for "steve"?
Both are no stop words. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is search field containing word 'steve' indexed?

Comment: Hi Ali, as I described "collection: tenants, fulltext index on answers.answer", yes it does have a index.